# How is cookie handled for multiple CORS requests

Tags: cookies, cors

Let's say I have a web app with domain myapp.com.
This web app will be mostly a client heavy app and will be making authenticated CORS requests (basically setting cookies) to multiple web sites, say abc.com and 1234.com.
Is there any way in current web standards to keep separate cookies for abc.com and 1234.com in client's browser?
The way I see it cookies are always set under myapp.com not to CORS requests.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will never send cookies of domain A to domain B.
If you have js code on myapp.com which issues a CORS request to abc.com, only the cookies of abc.com will be sent (if withCredentials was set to true).
Otherwise it would be a violation of [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

If you want to completely prevent JS code to read cookies you might want to use [HttpOnly flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

Comment: What will happen if I already authenticated to abc.com with cookies set, AND THEN authenticate to 1234.com which will also set cookies? Will it override abc.com's cookies?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No, 1234.com can't override cookies of abc.com. In general - Site A can't do anything to cookies in site B and CORS doesn't change this.

Comment: Hello guys. I'm facing a similar issue and I have a question on that. What if my 2 clients were abc.com and bcd.abc.com. Meaning domain and subdomain and my api.abc.com sets cookies to those clients during authentication. Can cookies be separated on browser while using them at the same time on the same browser? In my case logging in to the second client overrides the cookies of the first login